# pyspark (version 2.4) group by with sum not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data file which looks like this

```
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|InvoiceNo|StockCode|         Description|Quantity|        InvoiceDate|UnitPrice|CustomerID|       Country|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+
|   536365|   85123A|WHITE HANGING HEA...|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     2.55|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536365|    71053| WHITE METAL LANTERN|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536365|   84406B|CREAM CUPID HEART...|       8|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     2.75|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536365|   84029G|KNITTED UNION FLA...|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536365|   84029E|RED WOOLLY HOTTIE...|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     3.39|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536365|    22752|SET 7 BABUSHKA NE...|       2|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     7.65|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536365|    21730|GLASS STAR FROSTE...|       6|2010-12-01 08:26:00|     4.25|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536366|    22633|HAND WARMER UNION...|       6|2010-12-01 08:28:00|     1.85|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536366|    22632|HAND WARMER RED P...|       6|2010-12-01 08:28:00|     1.85|   17850.0|United Kingdom|
|   536367|    84879|ASSORTED COLOUR B...|      32|2010-12-01 08:34:00|     1.69|   13047.0|United Kingdom|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+----------+--------------+
```

when I run the following code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as sum_,count
relatil_data.groupBy('InvoiceNo').agg(sum_('UnitPrice'))
```

it works fine and gives output :

```
DataFrame[InvoiceNo: string, sum(UnitPrice): double]
```

but when I run below code

```
df=relatil_data.groupBy('InvoiceNo').agg(sum_('UnitPrice'))
df.show()
```

I get following error

```
    C:\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4839.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 198.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 198.0 (TID 214, localhost, executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\pg186028\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-e7aa0c35-ca53-4602-8411-bf816e010a46\17\temp_shuffle_f694f1cf-e72f-41b6-bf65-97ade34afc7c (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Same is happening when I try to create a view and run SQL on it.

Comment: Both would fail. The difference is that you're calling an action with `df.show()`. You need to solve the root cause (that file not found error)

Comment: @ernest_k: I am trying, but why am getting this error ?

Comment: @ernest_k: may be its because of double datatype in output data frame

Comment: Your code fails because Spark is loosing shuffle files. Typically a symptom of some bigger issue, and unlikely specific to code in question.

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue ( windows...), try setting spark scratch directory to something like c:\tmp

Answer (score -1):

Try with the below code without importing library file.

```
relatil_data.groupBy('InvoiceNo').agg("UnitPrice":"sum")
```

For changing the o/p column name from sum(UnitPrice) try below code

```
relatil_data.groupBy('InvoiceNo').agg("UnitPrice":"sum").withColumnRenamed("sum(UnitPrice)","Total_UnitPrice")
```

Comment: invalid syntax at : in "UnitPrice":"sum"

Comment: How did you created the dataframe ? Is it using below method

df = spark.read.format() ?

Comment: this is what I used : relatil_data=spark.read.option("inferSchema","true")\
.option("header","true")\
.option("inferSchema","true")\
.csv("2010-12-01.csv")

Comment: use Accolade inside pranteses: relatil_data.groupBy('InvoiceNo').agg({"UnitPrice":"sum"})